# Binding a SELECTED option in a laravel blade with laravel foreach and if statement

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

so i have this block of code that goes like such;

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="report.outlet">
          @foreach ($grSite as $pSite)
          @if($jsnUser['selectedSite'] == $pSite['iid'])
            <option selected value="{!! $pSite['iid'] !!}">{!! $pSite['profile']['firstName'] !!}</option>
          @endif
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </div></div>
```

so now here's the problem, when i load the page, all conditions are met, however my option is not automatically selected, it is selected on load, for like 0.5 seconds, and suddenly the select input just goes blank. why is this? also, i've already tried using an `@else` statement, but it does not work as well. any help would be much appreciated! if it's not clear yet, i'm using a laravel blade template, binding with angular, but this part is purely laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be selected because you are using ng-model. In your angular controller you have to give `report.outlet` a default value which is part of the options. Then according to that value, the option will be selected by default.

The reason it's selected for 0.5 is because angular isn't ready yet. as soon as Angular is ready, it goes blank.

Comment: ohhh fair enough, aaa, this is really messy hahah, i guess i need to use an ng-init now. thanks btw, @eddythedove ! :D

Comment: You dont have to use ng-init. but it's still ok. You could just echo your options in javascript and take them with angular.